# SolrJ Parallel Indexing from Oracle --> Solr (Java Concurrency - Multi-threading)

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, solr, cloudera

My Goal : Copy Data(1 001 000 Rows) from Oracle DB to Solr using SolrJ (everyday).

---

Machine: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 0 @ 2.70GHz(Virtual Machine - 8 Thread 16GB RAM)

---

My question aims at the strategy - which way is better to index 1 001 000 documents everyday?

- 10 Thread - so on each run app has to index 100 000 documents.
- 1 Thread 100000 doc
- 2 Thread 50 000 doc

I played around and here are the results:

- Single Thread 100 000 : 4 Minutes
- 2 Thread (50 000) : 2,45 minutes
- 4 thread (25 000) : 2,47 minutes
- 6 Thread (17 000) : 2:55 Minutes
- 8 Thread (12 500) : 3,06 Minutes
- 16 Thread (6250)  : 8,14 Minutes
- 4 Thread (125 000 doc on each thread) : 7 Minutes and 47 Seconds took to Index 1 001 000 rows.

Fact that 2 threaded process indexing is the fastest among others, but have no idea why...

P.S. On production JAR will be loaded as a job into Cloudera Hadoop System, with 100+ threads.

### CODE :

```
public class VehicleService {

private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Vehicles");

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SolrServerException {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    Long numberOfResults = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT (e.govNumber) FROM Vehicle e where e.active = 1", Long.class).getSingleResult();

    CloudSolrServer server = new CloudSolrServer("***");
    server.setDefaultCollection("vehicles");
    em.close();
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    List<Future<Integer>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Integer>>(1100000);

    for (int i=0; i<numberOfResults; i += 125000) {
        try {
            Task task = new Task(i, server, emf);
            Future<Integer> future = es.submit(task);
            futures.add(future);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    if (futures.isEmpty()) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    /*es.shutdown();*/
 /*        server.shutdown();*/

    /*int done = 0;

    while (done != futures.size()) {
        for (Future f : futures) {
            if (f.isDone()) {
                done += 1;
            }
        }
    }*/
}
 }

class Task implements Callable<Integer> {

int firstResult;
CloudSolrServer server;
EntityManagerFactory emf;

public Task(int firstResult, CloudSolrServer server, EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    this.firstResult = firstResult;
    this.server = server;
    this.emf = emf;
}

public Integer call() {
    try {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        List<Vehicle> vehicleList = em.createQuery("SELECT e from Vehicle e where e.active = 1", Vehicle.class).setFirstResult(firstResult).setMaxResults(125000).getResultList();
        em.close();
        server.addBeans(vehicleList);
        System.out.println("inserted : " + (firstResult +125000));
        System.out.println("VehicleList: " + vehicleList.size());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return firstResult;
}
}
```

Comment: 2 threads is enough to maximise whatever resource you are bottlenecked on.  My bet is you are limited by the speed you can extract data out of Oracle.  Try doing a bulk export instead.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
Ok, I'll try bulk export, but does Oracle support bulk export from Oracle to SOLR?

Comment: And I need only 4 columns, not complete table

Comment: You can do a bulk export of the result of a SELECT or stored procedure.